# Writing a test to call staking.chill() so as to remove Charlie as a Validator

Tags: polkadot-js, staking, testing, session

I am trying to write a test on PolkadotJS to `chill` Charlie Account so as to remove Charlie as a validator and then ascertain that Charlie has been removed. But, Charlie does not seem to have been removed as a validator, although the Chilled event got triggered on the Polkadot UI explorer.

```
    let call = polkadotApi.tx.staking.chill();
    await call.signAndSend(charlieStash);
```

More so, could it be that because Charlie is an invulnerable, that's why i cannot chill Charlie? If so, is there an extrinsic to call so as to remove Charlie as an invulnerable at first before calling `chill`?

Answer (score 7):

No, the issue here is not related to invulnerables.

Invulnerables are only immune to getting slashed when an offence occurs.

Instead, the issue here is probably that you need to wait a full session for the validator set to change, you should not expect that a chill action like this takes place immediately.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn
I actually waited 3 sessions, and i still see Charlie as part of the validators after the chill action

Comment: can you post your `impl pallet_staking::Config Runtime` and perhaps some logs that start with `runtime::`?